# Calendar agent - error: sql cached statement NSSQLiteStatement

Tags: macos, calendar

So after spending quite a lot of time trying to fix my iCalendar app
from the Spinning beach ball lag every time I make a new event or edit an event,
I found this error in the console application:

```
"error: sql cached statement NSSQLiteStatement <0x7f8eef4c0fd0> on entity 'Group' with sql text 'SELECT t0.Z_ENT, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZCOLORSTRING, t0.ZISENABLED, ....... ( t0.Z_PK IN (SELECT * FROM _Z_intarray0)  AND  t0.Z_ENT >= ? AND  t0.Z_ENT <= ?) ' failed due to missing variable binding for (null) with expecting bindings (
    "<NSSQLBindVariable: 0x7f8eef47bdd0>",
    "<NSSQLBindVariable: 0x7f8eef47be70>"
) but actual substitution variables {
    objects = "{<NSManagedObject: 0x7f8eef540140> (entity: ExchangePrincipal; id: 0x240092b <x-coredata://93547915-498F-4251-8E7E-23DD04782C04/ExchangePrincipal/p9> ; data: <fault>)}";
}


error: sql cached statement NSSQLiteStatement <0x7f8eef48daa0> on entity 'Attendee' with sql text 'SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZADDRESSSTRING, t0.ZCOMMONNAME, t0.ZEMAIL, t0.ZINCLUDEDINALLRESPONDED, t0.ZINVITERNAME, t0.ZISSELFINVITED, t0.ZLIKENESSDATASTRING, t0.ZOMITSYNCRECORD, t0.ZPROPOSALENDDATE, t0.ZPROPOSALSTARTDATE, t0.ZPROPOSALSTATUS, t0.ZROLE, t0.ZRSVP, t0.ZSCHEDULEAGENT, t0.ZSCHEDULEFORCESEND, t0.ZSCHEDULESTATUS, t0.ZSTATUS, t0.ZSTATUSMODIFIEDDATE, t0.ZTYPE, t0.ZEVENT, t0.ZMYATTENDEEFOREVENT FROM ZATTENDEE t0 WHERE  t0.ZMYATTENDEEFOREVENT IN (SELECT * FROM _Z_intarray0)  ' failed due to missing variable binding for (null) with expecting bindings (
) but actual substitution variables {
    destinations = "{0x122c009eb <x-coredata://93547915-498F-4251-8E7E-23DD04782C04/Event/p1163>, 0x1230009eb <x-coredata://93547915-498F-4251-8E7E-23DD04782C04/Event/p1164>, 0x1234009eb <x-coredata://93547915-498F-4251-8E7E-23DD04782C04/Event/p1165>, 0x123c009eb <x-coredata://93547915-498F-4251-8E7E-23DD04782C04/Event/p1167>, 0x1258009eb <x-coredata://93547915-498F-4251-8E7E-23DD04782C04/Event/p1174>, 0x1264009eb <x-coredata://93547915-498F-4251-8E7E-23DD04782C04/Event/p1177>, 0x126c009eb <x-coredata://93547915-498F-4251-8E7E-23DD04782C04/Event/p1179>, 0x127c009eb <x-coredata://93547915-498F-4251-8E7E-23DD04782C04/Event/p1183>, 0x1280009eb <x-coredata://93547915-498F-4251-8E7E-23DD04782C04/Event/p1184>, 0x1284009eb <x-coredata://93547915-498F-4251-8E7E-23DD04782C04/Event/p1185>}";
}"
```

There are around 8-10 of such errors each time I make a new event.
Can you please help me with this issue?
I already reinstalled mac os sierra few times,
but it made no difference.

Comment: Sadly I have the same problem on my machine. If you found a solution in the meantime, I would love to hear it.

Comment: Strangely the calendar is working is normally now, the error persists in console but the Calendar.app is responsive and fast.  I guess just don't touch it and leave it alone for a few days...

Comment: same here not apparent effect on the app but the console is littered with these messages...

Comment: I have a similar problem and the fact that I can't solve it simply bothers me quite a lot

Comment: Reinstalling MacOS fixed the issue, it was relatively painless due to my backups.

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me was a new clean install of the Mac OS.

Now I don't get the same issue (and Calendar is a pleasure to use),
but if the issue re-appears I will make an update.